# React Router won't redirect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, frontend, mern

The Problem that i want to render different component when i click on the link and pass props to the component in order to display the results. when i did so the app won't make the first step which is redirecting and mounting different component on the page

```
function SearchFlights() {
const [FlightNumber, setSearchFlightNumber] = useState(0);
const [ArrivalTime, setSearchArrivalTime] = useState(0);
const [DepartureTime, setSearchDeparturetime] = useState(0);
const [DepartureDate, setSearchDepartureDate] = useState(0);
const [ArrivalDate, setSearchArrivalDate] = useState(0);
const [DepartureTerminal, setSearchDepartureTerminal] = useState(0);
const [ArrivalTerminal, setSearchArrivalTerminal] = useState(0);
const [sendRequest, setSendRequest] = useState(false);
const [searchResults, setSearcResults] = useState({})
const obj = {
FlightNumber: FlightNumber,
ArrivalTime: ArrivalTime,
DepartureTime: DepartureTime,
DepartureDate: DepartureDate,
ArrivalDate: ArrivalDate,
ArrivalTerminal: ArrivalTerminal,
DepartureTerminal: DepartureTerminal

}
function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/searchflight', obj).then(() => {
        console.log("yes")
        setSendRequest(true);

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("i am here")
    })


}
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getresults').then((response) => {
        setSearcResults(response.data)
        console.log(searchResults);
        console.log("i got triggered now")
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("i am here")
    })

}, [sendRequest])



return (


    <div className="create">
        <h2>Search a Flight</h2>
        <form>
            <label>Enter Flight Number</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                required
                // value={flightNumber}
                name="flightnumber"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchFlightNumber(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label>Enter Arrival Time </label>
            <input
                placeholder="hateb2a date..."
                type="text"

                //  value={arrivalTime}
                name="arrivaltime"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchArrivalTime(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label>Enter Departure Time</label>
            <textarea
                placeholder="hateb2a date bardo"

                //  value={departure}
                name="departuretime"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchDeparturetime(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>

            <label>Enter Departure Date</label>
            <textarea
                placeholder="hateb2a date bardo"

                //  value={departure}
                name="departuredate"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchDepartureDate(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>



            <label>Enter Arrival Date</label>
            <textarea

                required
                //  value={economySeats}
                name="economyseats"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchArrivalDate(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
            <label>Enter Arrival Terminal</label>
            <textarea
                required
                //    value={businessSeats}
                name="businessseats"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchArrivalTerminal(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>


            <label>Enter Departure Terminal</label>
            <textarea
                required
                //    value={businessSeats}
                name="businessseats"
                onChange={(e) =>
setSearchDepartureTerminal(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
```

> This is the React Router step to Change the url

```
                <Link to="/getresults" onClick={handleClick}> Search Flight</Link>
                <Switch>

                    <Route path={"/getresults"} component={SearchResults} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </form>
    </div>


);
}

export default SearchFlights;
```

And here's the routes file

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from 'react';
import Home from '../src/Components/Home'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Flights from './Components/Flights';
import CreateFlight from './Components/CreateFlights';
import SearchFlights from './Components/SearchFlights';
import SearchResults from './Components/SearchResults'



function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);


  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Link to="/"> Home</Link>
        <Link to="/viewFlights"> view Flights</Link>
        <Link to="/createflight"> create Flight</Link>
        <Link to="/searchflight"> Search Flight</Link>
        {/* <Navbar /> */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/createFlight" exact component={CreateFlight} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/viewflights" exact component={Flights} />
          <Route path="/searchflight" exact component={SearchFlights} />
          <Route path="/getresults" component={SearchResults} />

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );


  function About() {
    return <h2>About</h2>;
  }

  function Users() {
    return <h2>Users</h2>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: On which route this **SearchFlights** component is rendering? Please share that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL shown when you click on the Link?

You may want to put either

`<Route path={"getresults"} component={SearchResults} />` (if you have a `/` route defined)

or

`<Route exact path={"/getresults"} component={SearchResults} />` (for something like localhost:xxxx/getresults)

Comment: i want to redirect to localhost:xxxx/getresults and i have a '/'page but it won't change the url in the browser when i click on the link

Comment: I think you are setting the routing logic in the wrong place. 

Move all <Router> , <Switch> and <Routes> to another file (not inside the <form>) leaving only the <Link> (so you can click on it).

This file with all the routing is the one you want to use in the App.js so it declares how urls are mapped to each component.

So you can have something like
`<Router>
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={SearchFlight} />
   <Route exact path="/getresults" component={GetResults} />
 </Switch>
</Router>`

Comment: Also, you will be moving between pages and components so you may want to use `useHistory` to push the results of axios to the `/getresults` page. 

<Link> is generally used for plain navigation, for a simple change of page. If you want to send data to another page, you need to use a combination of `useHistory` and `useLocation` (and using a submit <button>)

Comment: I Have moved all the routes to one file which had previous routes but the problem still presists that the browser won't change the link url

Comment: Share that file code with all the routes mentioned in there. @MidoAshraf

Comment: @Ammar I have added the routes file to the question

Comment: "when i did so the app won't make the first step which is redirecting and mounting different component on the page"

What does it mean? Do you want to redirect to the "/getresults" page when the user opens up the "/searchflight" page? Because this code is working fine on my end.

Comment: i want to redirect when the user presses on the link i have created